# Set of circles in an intersection graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm not wanting the answer directly to this question. I've been working on this for hours and am just wanting some help and guidance on how to go about doing this question.

Let $\Omega$ be a set of circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$, each of which has radius equal to 1.  Consider the set of all $\Omega$-intersections graphs and call it $\mathcal{G}$. Determine two different graphs, call them $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$, such that if a  graph G has $\mathcal{F}_1$ or $\mathcal{F}_2$ as an induced subgraph, then G cannot belong to $\mathcal{G}$.

The trouble that I'm having is trying to figure out What G is. Then how to build $F_1$ and $F_2$ based on that information. I'm extremely frustrated and could really use a hand.

Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to find $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that for any graph G, we have the implication: ($G$ contains $H_1$ or $H_2$) implies ($G$ is not such an intersection graph). Stated in the contrapositive, you have to find two graphs $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that they are guaranteed not to be present as induced subgraphs in any intersection graph. Note that the induced subgraph of an intersection graph is also an intersection graph.

Thus all you need is to find two graphs $H_1$ and $H_2$ which you can prove cannot be represented as intersection graphs.